# Is it possible for the google maps api to plot international directions?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

The four travelling methods are `DRIVING` (default), `BICYCLING`, `TRANSIT` and `WALKING`. What I'm wondering is if it is possible to use the maps API to plot internationally - not just regionally. Is this a non-trivial implementation of the API or am I overlooking something? It may be possible to crowbar a solution by manipulating existing maps url queries but I'm not sure if this is what I will need to do or if there is an existing way with the API.

Answer (score 0):

It can plot but Google Map will suggest you for a fly option on a map and it will direct you to flight booking. anyway, it will show you car path and public transportation option. Moreover, it will allow you if the direction on a ground vehicle is possible if not it will show only flight route to direction.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. With the default option `DRIVING` or `TRANSIT` it does not elect a direct flight path. Not sure you really have used the API or not...

Answer (score 0):

Another way to perform this task is to create a custom map and draw custom lines yourself.

You can watch a good tutorial @ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2BqXHqIXjSU

And start creating custom maps @ https://www.google.com/maps/d/home.